# Hide scrollbars in old windows console(pre windows 10 one)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with hiding scrollbars in an old Windows console while simultaneously allowing the console to being resized.  My code works on a new console, but on an old console:

1. it works, but prevents the console window from being resized to a larger size(attempt a).
2. scrollbars start behaving incorrectly after window resizing. They sometimes are hidden, sometimes only one is hidden, and sometimes one is cut in half(attempt b).

Here is my code:

```
#include "windows.h"

int main()
{
    HANDLE console_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;)
    {

        // attempt a)
        /*CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO buffer_info;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console_handle, &buffer_info);

        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(
            console_handle,
            { buffer_info.srWindow.Right - buffer_info.srWindow.Left + 1, buffer_info.srWindow.Bottom - buffer_info.srWindow.Top + 1 }
        );*/


        //attempt b)
        HWND w = GetConsoleWindow();
        ShowScrollBar(w, SB_BOTH, FALSE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're running in an infinite busy loop, I'm not surprised the console misbehaves.

Comment: It misbehaves even if these functions are called once a second.

Comment: Modifying the scrollbars probably cancels the modal resizing loop. What you're doing is not supported. The console window isn't "yours".

Answer (score 0):

Generally the hWnd of a console window is not guaranteed to be suitable for all window handle operations as, for example, documented [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/124103/how-to-obtain-a-console-window-handle-hwnd). 
It is not a "real window", So you can't expect its behavior.